# Using JWT with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, x509certificate, jwt, jose4j

I'm trying to adapt this example to use with GAE: https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples

Above example requires a private key (secret) to sign JWT header + payload. [AppIdentityService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/appidentity/AppIdentityService) provides a way to sign arbitrary bytes but it does not explain how to verify the signature using `PublicCertificate`.

I need help to identify 2 things-

1. How to store and manage secret key in Google App Engine?
2. How to verify signature using AppIdentityService?

A reference to some working example which uses JWT with GAE would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

An adaptation of the example at https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/JWT%20Examples that should work, if GAE signs using RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using SHA-256, is in the first comment of https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/issues/33/using-jwt-with-google-app-engine